# C++ invoke Java function to get Array of JavaClassObject using JNI

Tags: java, c++, arrays, android-ndk, java-native-interface

i am developing an app in Unreal Engine so base coding is in C++, and i have to access some methods from .jar

i have accessed simple java function returning: boolean, int, string (native data types):

```
JavaMethod_GetJavaString  = JavaClassObject_Manager->GetClassMethod("GetJavaString", "()Ljava/lang/String;");
```

and i call this method as:

```
jstring myJStr = static_cast<jstring>(JavaClassObject_Manager->CallMethod<jobject>(JavaMethod_GetJavaString));
JNIEnv* Env = AndroidApplication::GetJavaEnv();
const char* myUTFString = Env->GetStringUTFChars(myJStr, nullptr);
std::string myCStr(UTF8_TO_TCHAR(myUTFString));
```

but above code is for getting single string from JAVA, i want an array of JAVA Objects. as i am looking for JAVA and JNI, i came across 'jarray' and 'jobjectarray'. but could not find any documentation or example to get an array of java objects in C++

Answer (score 0):

An array of Strings would be a `jobjectArray`.

To get a particular String from that array, you would use `GetObjectArrayElement`, which gives you a `jobject` that you can just cast to `jstring`.

Then extract the strings contents the same way you already are, except that you should of course call `ReleaseStringUTFChars` afterwards.

And finally call `DeleteLocalRef` on your `jstring` (you may have to cast it back to `jobject`).

See [the JNI Functions documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/technotes/guides/jni/spec/functions.html) for more details on these functions.